# Would it hurt SEO for a sitemap to be hosted on a different domain if you 301 direct to it?

Tags: seo, sitemap

We compute our sitemap periodically with a `cron job` and store the results in `s3`.

Can we `301` redirect https://oursite.com/sitemap.xml to the sitemap.xml hosted on `s3`?

I know that the sitemap spec requires the sitemap to be on the same domain (http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#location). But would a `301` to an `off-domain` `URL` be treated by the major search providers as being on the same domain or off of it?

Comment: [Cross-post on Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/82972/17633).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about SEO, not programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Webmasters (and there is already a duplicate there).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can. In short, you have to prove that you own the parent site, and you can do that by including the sitemap's URL from s3 in the robots.txt file of the parent site.

Parent site's robots.txt should get a section like:

```
# myawesomesite.com/robots.txt

[...]
Sitemap: http://s3.yoursite.com/sitemap.xml
```

See more in [Sitemaps & Cross Submits section of Sitemaps.Org](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#sitemaps_cross_submits)

Comment: Thanks -- not sure how I missed that section on sitemaps.org, but I appreciate you pointing it out.